# Why are bonuses paid out by Coinbase set as type "send"?

Tags: coinbase-api

This seems like a mistake in the classification of the transaction type. It should be a "buy" or a new type of some sort like "bonus", no?

```
{
        "id": "c06b1025-d339-53f6-b439-f9b087502152",
        "type": "send",
        "status": "completed",
        "amount": {
            "amount": "0.00059300",
            "currency": "BTC"
        },
        "native_amount": {
            "amount": "9.99",
            "currency": "USD"
        },
        "description": "Congrats! You just earned a $10 bonus for inviting your friend ****** to Coinbase. They received the same bonus. Earn more by inviting your friends with this link: https://www.coinbase.com/join/52957440cf2d06a92a0000bb",
        "created_at": "2017-12-13T21:31:40Z",
        "updated_at": "2017-12-13T21:31:40Z",
        "resource": "transaction",
        "resource_path": "/v2/accounts/6401de05-e7a3-5320-a2dc-867df3ff3c0a/transactions/c06b1025-d339-53f6-b439-f9b087502152",
        "instant_exchange": false,
        "network": {
            "status": "off_blockchain"
        },
        "from": {
            "id": "7fd10cd7-b091-5cee-ba41-c29e49a7cccf",
            "resource": "user",
            "resource_path": "/v2/users/7fd10cd7-b091-5cee-ba41-c29e49a7cccf",
            "currency": "BTC"
        },
        "details": {
            "title": "Received Bitcoin",
            "subtitle": "From Coinbase"
        }
    }
```

Comment: It’s a bonus being sent from Coinbase to you. See the `"details"` field. How would `"buy"` make sense?

Comment: @Ryan Because you're receiving the funds. All "buys" are positive "credits" to your currency amount. Sends are negatives.

Comment: But the `"from"` field isn't you in this case, presumably, and the `"amount"` is positive.

Comment: Fair... I still think bonuses should not be of type `buy`.

Answer (score 1):

a buy is a two-way transaction... you're giving something, and getting something

a send is a one-way transaction... either you're giving to someone, or someone is giving to you

coinbase is getting nothing from you (other than the friend you referred) but they are giving you money, so it's a simple send